# Paper wallet generator that can split a private key into multiple parts like a multi-sig transaction?

Tags: multi-signature, paper-wallet

Are there any paper wallets that lets you split a private key into multiple parts like how a multi-sig transaction works? Sure I can just print out a paper wallet and cut it up into 4 pieces and give one to each user, but I'm wondering has anyone solved such an issue? A good use case is cutting up a private key and giving each one to a family member. In order to form the private key back, all parties must be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.bitaddress.org](https://www.bitaddress.org) offers something similar to your description. It's under the `Split Wallet` tab once you generate enough entropy. You can even specify a m-of-n multisig.